Compositor file output node disregards its color transform setting
When I render out an image sequence in Multilayer EXR using the compositor file output node, with AGX logarithmic transform set in the node's properties, the file comes out in Linear Rec.709 transform instead. But, when I use the sequencer via the post-processing check box, the sequence does come out in AGX logarithmic, which is what I want.

From my brief research it looks like you might be able to set the output node’s color transform in the Compositing editor sidebar.

Yes... But it will always export in linear rec 709 from the compositor

Does this answer your question? EXR Output Overexposed
